# To replace internet acronyms in a dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining

I'm working on a text mining project where I'm trying to replace abbreviations, slang words and internet acronyms present in text (In a dataframe column) using a manually prepared dictionary.

The problem I'm facing is the code stops with the first word of the text in the dataframe column and does not replace it with lookup words from dict

Here is the sample dictionary and code I use:

```
abbr_dict = {"abt":"about", "b/c":"because"}

def _lookup_words(input_text):
    words = input_text.split()
    new_words = [] 
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in abbr_dict:
            word = abbr_dict[word.lower()]
        new_words.append(word)
        new_text = " ".join(new_words) 
        return new_text
df['new_text'] = df['text'].apply(_lookup_words)
```

Example Input:

```
df['text'] =
However, industry experts are divided ab whether a Bitcoin ETF is necessary or not.
```

Desired Output:

```
df['New_text'] =
However, industry experts are divided about whether a Bitcoin ETF is necessary or not.
```

Current Output:

```
df['New_text'] =
However
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as following with using `lambda` and `join` along with `split`:

```
import pandas as pd

abbr_dict = {"abt":"about", "b/c":"because"}

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['However, industry experts are divided abt whether a Bitcoin ETF is necessary or not.']})

df['new_text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda row: " ".join(abbr_dict[w] 
                             if w.lower() in abbr_dict else w for w in row.split()))
```

---

Or to fix the code above, I think you need to move the `join` for `new_text` and `return` statement outside of the `for` loop:

```
def _lookup_words(input_text):
    words = input_text.split()
    new_words = [] 
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in abbr_dict:
            word = abbr_dict[word.lower()]
        new_words.append(word)
    new_text = " ".join(new_words) # ..... change here
    return new_text # ..... change here also
df['new_text'] = df['text'].apply(_lookup_words)
```